# get_git_version cannot find version number

Tags: django, git

In `version.py` there is a method `get_git_version()` when I execute `./manage.py runserver` this error is raised from `version.py` file

> raise ValueError("Cannot find the version number!")

```
def get_git_version(abbrev=4):
    # Read in the version that's currently in RELEASE-VERSION.

    release_version = read_release_version()

    # First try to get the current version using "git describe".

    version = call_git_describe(abbrev)

    # If that doesn't work, fall back on the value that's in
    # RELEASE-VERSION.

    if version is None:
        version = release_version

    # If we still don't have anything, that's an error.

    if version is None:
        raise ValueError("Cannot find the version number!")

    # If the current version is different from what's in the
    # RELEASE-VERSION file, update the file to be current.

    if version != release_version:
        write_release_version(version)

    # Finally, return the current version.

    return version


def read_release_version():
    try:
        f = open("RELEASE-VERSION", "r")

        try:
            version = f.readlines()[0]
            return version.strip()

        finally:
            f.close()
    except:
        return None
```

Comment: def read_release_version():
    try:
        f = open("RELEASE-VERSION", "r")

        try:
            version = f.readlines()[0]
            return version.strip()

        finally:
            f.close()

    except:
        return None

Comment: Check the path for 'RELEASE-VERSION' file. Also check by attaching the file extension while opening it, like 'RELEASE-VERSION.txt'.

Comment: where is call_git_describe() defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script is expecting a version number either from a git annotated tag (`call_git_describe()`), or by looking version number in a file named `RELEASE-VERSION`. It fails because none of these two things are found, so fix one of them.

Run this in your project to create annotated tag for the current commit:

```
git tag 1.0 -m "this is version 1.0"
```

I tend to prefer tagging for version management, but version in a text file is also good, YMMV.